# LINQ: Return non-duplicate Items in a List

Tags: c#, linq, list

If I have a list like this:

```
List<int> test = new List<int>{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6 , 7 , 7 , 7};
```

Then using the .Distinct() method:

```
var distinctTest = test.Distinct();
```

Will make the result list like this:
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }

How can I make a distinct item list like this:
{ 5, 6 }

Comment: I'm sure this *must* be a duplicate, but I can't find it quickly... `test.GroupBy(x => x).Where(g => g.Count() == 1).Select(g => g.Key)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So you want to remove all items which are duplicates?

You can use `GroupBy`:

```
var distinctTest = test
    .GroupBy(i => i)
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
test.Select(x => x).Distinct();
```

This will return a sequence (IEnumerable) of your values -- one per unique value.

Comment: You seem to have misread the question - the OP already said they didn't want this. Not sure who upvoted this - it's just wrong.