# C# Linq find unique item

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking for a way to find items in a list that are unique:

```
List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
list.Add(new Item() { id = 1, name = "test" });
list.Add(new Item() { id = 2, name = "test" });
list.Add(new Item() { id = 3, name = "test1"});
list.Add(new Item() { id = 4, name = "test2"});
list.Add(new Item() { id = 5, name = "test2"});

var uniqueItems = ?
```

uniqueItems should contain { id = 3, name = "test1"} because test1 is unique

Whats the best way to implement that?

Comment: I don't get what makes `{ id = 3, name = "test1"}`  more unique than `{ id = 2, name = "test"}` or `{ id = 4, name = "test2"}`

Comment: You post a requirement, not a question. What problem did you face trying this?

Comment: What do you mean by "unique"? Which attributes should be unique? The id? The name? Or the comboination of both?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain maybe it is slightly ambiguous, but OP does say *"because test1 is unique"*, and gives *"test1"* as an example, which implies `name` determines uniqueness.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513214/linq-return-non-duplicate-items-in-a-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the linq operators Where and Count like

```
var uniqueItems = list.Where(x => list.Count(item => item.name == x.name) == 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Several ways (using `Linq`):

```
var uniqueItems = list.Where(item => list.Count(li => String.Equals(item.name, li.name)) == 1);

//or

var uniqueItems = list
    .GroupBy(item => item.name)
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
    .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Answer (score 2):

```cs
list.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Where(x => x.Count() == 1)
    .Select(x => new Item { id = x.First().id, name = x.Key });
```